# Custom validation code call fails

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I am developing an API using Codeigniter 2.0.3.
I need to validate users and then output the errors. I have extended the Form validation library with a custom function but I only get error when calling it.

Strange thing is that it works offline (on my local mac) but not on the remote server.

**The validation code in the controller:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules ('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run () == FALSE) {

  $errors = $this->form_validation->get_error_array ();

  respond (count($errors), '422', $errors, TRUE);

}
```

**The custom function in My_form_validation which is located in application/core:**

```
function get_error_array() {

 return $this->_error_array;

}
```

**The error message:**

```
Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::get_error_array()
```

**The constructor in the MY_form_validation file:**

```
public function MY_Form_validation ($config) {

 parent::__construct ($config);

}
```

Comment: did you ever figure that out?  I the same problem where I get an error "Call to undefined method..."  when extending the CI_Form_Validation class.  BUT ONLY ON MY REMOTE SERVER !  not on my localhost.

Comment: I realized the problem that I was having and you were most likely having the same issue.  I named my Class MY_Form_validation, however my file name was all lower case.  my_form_validation.php.

Obviously for me this is a server configuration difference between my host and my localhost where case-sensitivity is not the same.  

It does clarify this in the user_guide under the Naming Conventions section...
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The custom function in My_form_validation which is located in
>   application/core:

The file MY_Form_validation.php should be put in `application/libraries` since the Form Valition library isn't a core library.

Comment: Try removing the __construct() from MY_Form_validation. It's not needed if you don't use the construct for anything. And the construct could be your problem. If not, the problem lies elsewhere in what you mentioned above.

Comment: Still errors. I moved the code into the core file and it helped. But I think it is better to extend.

Comment: Again, I believe the error must lie else where. Generating an empty CI installation, extending the CI_Form_validation class works like expected (no __construct used).